# How to run a method after a boolean change in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So I have a method called: `- (void)spawnNode` and it basically regulates the spawning of my Node. My problem is that I want to make it so that when the `BOOL runGame` equals `YES` the spawnNode method will begin and keep spawning my node after intervals of time. Which I don't know how to do.

The `BOOL runGame` is initially set to `NO`.

**Below is the full spawnNode method:**

```
- (void)spawnNode{
    //Spawn Interval Duration
    spawnIntervalDuration = 0.75;

    //SKAction spawnInterval
    spawnInterval = [SKAction waitForDuration:spawnIntervalDuration];

    if(runGame){
        [self runAction:spawnInterval completion:^{
            [self generateNode];
        }];
    }
}
```

So, How do I make this method always run whilst `runGame` is equal to `YES`?

Comment: Call spawnNode in the completion. Also, call spawnNode whenever runGame gets set to YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL runGame;
```

Also, a NSTimer property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

Then, you need to override the setter for it:

```
- (void)setRunGame:(BOOL)newValue
{
  if (newValue == YES) {
    [self spawnNode];

    CGFloat spawnInterval = 0.75;

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:spawnInterval
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(spawnNode)
                                                userInfo:kNilOptions
                                                 repeats:YES];
  } else {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ppalancia This works well, however, there is one problem. It makes the same drop 5 frames occasionally.

Comment: Can you explain in more simple words? I am not native English speaker, not sure if I understand the problem you just mentioned.

Comment: Conceptually, this answer is correct. However, I would advise against using NSTimer over an SKAction solution in a SpriteKit game. Reason being that when you pause the game via SpriteKit, NSTimer does not get paused, while an SKAction does.  Just a heads up, as this answer is conceptually right in how you should handle the BOOL setting. Just swap out the NSTimer for SKAction specific solution for spawn timer.

Comment: @prototypical Hi, yeah I figured that out a while ago, but thanks :)

What I did was make SKActions instead of the NSTimer. One was:

generateNode = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(generateNode) onTarget:self];